# Determine if A is a linear combination of B when a free variable exists

Tags: linear-algebra

$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&5\\-2&1&-6&\\0&2&8
\end{pmatrix}$, $B =
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\-1\\6
\end{pmatrix}$

From $A$ and $B$ I have created an augmented matrix

$\sim\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&5&2\\-2&1&-6&-1\\0&2&8&6
\end{pmatrix}$

Which in rref is

$\sim\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&5&2\\0&1&4&3\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$

The bottom row of zeros in addition to the lack of a pivot in the third row  indicates that a free variable exists for $x_3$. This means that infinitely many solutions exist for the system of equations.

Does the infinite number of solution imply that $B$ would be a linear combination of $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by "Does the infinite number of solution imply that $B$ would be a linear combination of $A$?"? $B$ is the right-hand side (constants) of the system of equations $A$.

Comment: Yes, and I know that if a unique solution exists then B would indeed be a linear combination of A. What I am unclear on is since infinitely many solutions exist as opposed to just one unique solution is B still a linear combination of A

Comment: What does a vector being a linear combination of a matrix mean? I think you're confusing things here, but I'm not sure which ones.

Comment: Well, the linear system $Ax=B$ is consistent "has at least one solution" iff $B$ is a linear combination of the **columns** of $A$ (i.e., if $B$ is in the span of the columns of $A$). So yes for a system with infinitely many solutions and according to this definition, as long as the system is consistent, $B$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Moreover, once you reach the reduced row echelon form, the column with the free variable can be written as a linear combination of the other columns of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score -1):

$B$ would not be a linear combination of $A$. In fact, it could not ever be do to the difference in dimension if the two matrices. $B_{3X1}$ while $A_{3X3}$. See Meshal's comment.